Webview inside ModalBottomSheet is not scrollable in android compose
I am loading webview inside ModalBottomSheet. But webview is not scrolling.
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.background(color = MaterialTheme.customColorsPalette.colorF6F7FC),
        factory = {
            WebView(it).apply {
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
                webViewClient = WebViewClient()

                // Enable JavaScript if needed
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                settings.builtInZoomControls = true
                settings.displayZoomControls = false
                settings.useWideViewPort = true
                settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
                settings.setSupportZoom(true)
                isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true
                isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = true

                loadUrl(url)
            }
        },
        update = {
            it.loadUrl(url)
        }
    )
}

This compose method i am calling from ModalBottomSheet. But webview content is not scrolling

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73969290/webview-inside-of-the-bottom-sheet-of-the-bottomsheetscaffold-is-not-scrollable
